# Windows Authentication possible in metro app?

Tags: microsoft-metro

I want to retrieve the username of the logged-in user. Is it possible? The app is for intranet only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To add Windows authentication to an app, declare the ['enterpriseAuthentication' capability](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211423.aspx) in the manifest.

Refer to the info in [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11181821/providing-domain-user-credentials-to-webview-control) for more details.

Edit:

To retrieve the domain name of the user, I believe you can use [`Windows.System.UserProfile.UserInformation.GetDomainNameAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.userprofile.userinformation.getdomainnameasync).  There is also the [User domain name sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/User-domain-name-sample-85ce3e49) on MSDN.

Comment: I have already enabled `Enterprise Authentication, Internet (Client), Private Networks (Client & Server)`. I'm able to open an Intranet URL in a WebView without the credential prompt. But in my XAML code, I want to retrieve the domainname\username so I can call a WebAPI which takes the username as the input and returns some user-specific data which needs to be on the tile.

Comment: Thanks for the edit! The sample is just what I wanted. I was able to retrieve the domainname and username. Thanks Nathan!!

Comment: The relevant code in the sample is marked as async - `async void GetDNSDomain_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)` as the code is using an `async` operation - `GetPrincipalNameAsync`. I wanted to retrieve the name in the `OnNavigatedTo` event. Is there a non-async way of retrieving it?

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh452713.aspx for more info on working with Async methods.