# Windows Authentication on Raspberry Pi 2 running Windows IoT

Tags: raspberry-pi, windows-authentication, win-universal-app, raspberry-pi2, windows-10-iot-core

I'm on a network where I need my Raspberry Pi to be windows authenticated in order to reach out of the network or to connect to any intranet sites. Due to this I can't even test my WebView component properly other than sending html directly to `WebView.NavigateToString()`.

My question is how do I set up Windows Authentication in Windows 10 IoT for Raspberry Pi?

Comment: This answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11181821/providing-domain-user-credentials-to-webview-control) is for Windows 8, but should work for UWP too.